# Trouble importing FENiCS Dolfin on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and python 2.7.6, and have had trouble running importing DOLFIN from [FEniCS](https://fenicsproject.org). I used the following commands to install, as suggested by FENiCS documentation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fenics-packages/fenics
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fenics
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

No errors occurred during installation, but when running the command

```
from dolfin import *
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dolfin/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import cpp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dolfin/cpp/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    exec("from . import %s" % module_name)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dolfin/cpp/function.py", line 209, in <module>
    class GenericFunction(ufc.function, common.Variable):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'function'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across the same problem, I received a useful response to this [here](https://fenicsproject.org/qa/10912/trouble-importing-dolfin-on-ubuntu-14-04).

In short, somehow in my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fenics-packages-fenics-trust.list` file, I had this line for some reason:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fenics-packages/fenics-exp/ubuntu trusty main
```

And the experimental builds are not compatible with Ubuntu 14.04. I manually changed 'fenics-exp' to 'fenics' and reinstalled, and it works now.